# Define an abstract class without any implementation

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

If I define an abstract class with abstract members and without any Generalization is a well design in Object Oriented Design?Can I Replace it with an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned in the linked answers... an interface can have only public methods and properties, while an abstract class can define public and protected properties, methods, and fields. So if your abstract class has any of those, no, you cannot replace it with an interface.

Comment: Which language are you referring to, and why do you believe that is the same language as the OP?

Comment: I'm referring to c#, because I looked at the [OP's profile page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40559/m-azad). I agree the answer is not universal.